# var_dumpをファイル出力する際、多次元の下の階層まで表示する方法はありますか？

Tags: php

var_dumpをファイル出力すると、

```
ob_start();
var_dump($a);
$b =ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$fp = fopen("./out.txt", "a+" );
fputs($fp, $b);
fclose( $fp );
```

下の階層が下記のように...で表示されます

```
  public $hoge =>
  array(1) {
    ...
  }
```

---

var_exportを使用するばすべて表示されるのですが、var_dumpでも同じように表示させることはできますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Xdebug`の設定ってどうなっておりますか？
設定を下記のように変更してみてはいかがでしょう？

```
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_children', -1);
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_data', -1);
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth', -1);
ob_start();
var_dump($a);
$b =ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
$fp = fopen("./out.txt", "a+" );
fputs($fp, $b);
fclose( $fp );
```

Comment: 回答いただいたコードを試したら、これまで表示されなかった下層も無事表示されるようになりました！　phpinfoで「Xdebug」を確認してみました。xdebug.var_display_max_depth 3。xdebug.var_display_max_children 128。xdebug.var_display_max_data 512 となっていました